# Large Select Drop down convert to Filter UL List with Legacy jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, list, select, filter, legacy

Ok here goes...

Project is running jQuery 1.3.2 (There are plans to upgrade/rewrite but not at this current stage). The select drop down menu has a couple hundred options. My goal is to do something like the [Chosen Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) (Standard Select) with the filter and scrolling functionality. This select menu is generated from a custom framework (I didn't write).

Looking for any:

- Tips
- Help
- Points in the right direction
- Outside of the box ideas

I've tried to use the chosen plugin using jQuery in No Conflict but that didn't go over well.

Comment: something like this help?  http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/6zcRk/  Be easy to parse a select to create LI's and add a bit more functionality

Comment: That's awesome but I'm working with jQuery 1.3.2 and it's already a select element which I need to transform into something like this +1 for effort though

Comment: parsing from select is just a couple of lines and same code as in 1.7. Just a  few lines to bind the clcik handler back to select also if you need to keep the select. Not sure what your ultimate goal is

Comment: slight modifications using select to build list in 1.3.2 and pass value back to select on clcik. If want as a plugin could do it in less than 1/2 hour  http://jsfiddle.net/6zcRk/1/

Comment: @charlietfl Please add you last solution as the answer, works great!!! Big thanks

Comment: not following what you mean...  if you mean as plugin, not sure exactly how would want it to be implemented. Have to consider target list vs select fro example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo of a dropdown unordered list "pseudo" select generated dynamically from options of a select tag. Clicking on list items updates values in select

jsfiddle.net/6zcRk/1